# Tools for testing correct processing of user input in a Webform

Tags: php, mysql, testing

I wrote a web-application using PHP+MySQL for a part of a course in my universtity. Part of the report that I have to write should includes a part on testing of the application.

So my question is what are the best tools that I can use to perform tests to proove that what the user inputs into a form is what is actually saved on the database. I perform client side validation with JavaScript using regular expressions to assure that the input is valid, but I also have to show that the correct values are being written on the DB. What is the standard way to this? Are there any tools (free) that I can use?

Comment: Why not query the database and print the values?

Comment: @ Tekin This is what I am doing now. I just wanted to know if there were more sophiticated tools to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automated unit tests, Adrian already pointed you to a good solution.

You can also automate browser-based testing with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't perform only client side validation. You should always do server side validation! What if I write php script that posts your form? Then your client side validation wouldn't work and I can put invalid data in your database.

For testing in php look at [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/)